# How to delete all the rows of a table?

Tags: snmp, mib

I need to add functionality to the existing mib and agent code to delete all the rows of a table (i.e. clear the contents of a table).

I know how to delete a single row (using the rowstatus "destroy"), but how to delete all the rows in one go?

Answer (score 0):

As You already know, the deletion of a row is a side-effect of changing the rowstatus column. You could use a special object next to the table which would clear the table itself.

NOTE: One of the rules of SNMP is avoiding redundancy. The SNMP manager can already delete the whole table content by deleting the rows one by one.